# Haskell - Taking input during runtime

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I can't figure out how to accept input from the user during code execution. Say I type this code:

```
import System.IO

main = do  
    putStrLn "Hi, what's your name?"  
    name <- getLine  
    putStrLn ("Hi " ++ name)
```

Well, I want the text `"Hi, what's your name?"` to show up *before* I type in my name, then print the second line `"Hi, name"` *after* the user types their name.
However, as it is right now, none of the text shows up until *after* I type my name. This makes the question redundant, since the question is not presented to the user until after they have answered it.

I know this may be a noobish question, but I've been googling it for a long time with no success. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me. Perhaps you're using it wrong. How are you calling it?

Comment: Are you sure you are using `putStrLn` like in the above code, and not `putStr`? It sounds like a buffering problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably due to the default buffering on your system. Try explicitly setting the buffering modes to line buffering using [hSetBuffering](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hSetBuffering):

```hs
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering
    hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
    putStrLn "Hi, what's your name?"  
    name <- getLine  
    putStrLn ("Hi " ++ name)
```

Comment: AFAIK line buffering should be the default in all sane implementations when stdout is connected to a terminal. If this works I would still look for the root cause elsewhere.

Comment: This fixed it, thanks. and @user2847643, I'll look into it.